# 'I know to drive' or 'I know how to drive'

Tags: grammar, verbs

> I know to drive.

or

> I know **how** to drive.

Are both sentences grammatically correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In some languages, there are separate words for knowing a fact, knowing a person, knowing how to do something, etc. In English, there is only one word, but we always add "how to" when we are talking about knowing how to do something. The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know?q=know%2Bhow%2Bto%2Bdo%2Bsth) has a separate entry for **know how to *do something***:

> to be able to do something because you have the necessary knowledge

If you just say **know to *do something***, it means that you know that it is **important** to do something:

> I **know to** put my hand in front of my mouth when I cough

In modern English this is used far more often in the negative to mean that it's important **not** to do something, for example:

> ...now **I know not to** mess with people's cars because it can get you in a lot of trouble... - [Say Uncle (Garland Stewart, 2009)](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=i9UJA4R0rSwC&pg=PA192&dq=%22i%20know%20not%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDkvK68P3cAhWMMY8KHVqICuAQ6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=%22i%20know%20not%20to%22&f=false)

Answer (score -1):

'**I know how to drive**' is the correct one. But you can see 'I know to drive' in certain positions in texts. example:

One thing *I knew, to drive* east as fast as possible.

One thing I knew, that I had to drive east, as fast as possible.

Comment: Although technically correct, from a learner's point of view the answer is confusing. Could you explain the difference in meaning, please?